# PGF generated with matplotlib contourf produces artifacts in pdf

Tags: matplotlib

I generate a contourplot with [`matplotlib.pyplot.contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) that produces a nice preview image:

[image]

But when I include the image into my document (using the exact same settings that I successfully employ for 1D plots) I observe some artifacts in the pdf (screenshot):
[image]

Again, as I have no problems for 1D (scatter, line) plots, I suspect that this has something to do with `contourf`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32911755/10456105) post - it is an issue of `matplotlib` instead of Latex.

One needs to set the colors of the edges as

```
cnt = plt.contourf(x, y, z)

for c in cnt.collections:
    c.set_edgecolor("face")
```